# Logitech g520 in Wow

Tags: wine, 14.10, games

Anyone know how to get the extra buttons working in WoW on a Logitech g520?
I am running Ubuntu 14.10 and WoW in wine 1.7.39. I have tried installing the software from Logitech with wine, but it doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is having this problem, I managed to solve it. I hooked the mouse up to a windows system, installed the software, and assigned keystroke macros to the keys that weren't working (ctrl-c, crtl-x, ect.) This allowed me to assign the buttons in game. This is a nice work around until Logitech finally gives us Linux support!